# Dynamically assign value to properties of an instance with the type of an interface

Tags: typescript

Previously in Typescript 3.3 it was possible to define a variable with "keyof interface" keyword as a type which would allow the dynamic access to properties of instances with type of said interface.

I want to use this in order to write a function that takes a field and value as parameters and assigns the value to the field of an object. This function can then be called from multiple input fields inside my React application like so:

```
 interface Product {
  id: number
  name: string
  price_amount: number
  price_currency: string
}

const myProduct = {
  id: 0,
  name: "My Product",
  price_amount: 100,
  price_currency: "€",
}
  
function handleObjectFieldUpdate(field: keyof Product, value: string) {
  {...} // Convert value to the respective type 
  myProduct[field] = value
}
```

In Typescript 4.3 however this code does no longer compile with the error
`Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'never'.ts(2322)`.

Link to compiling [Typescript 3.3 Example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=3.3.3#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgApQPYBMCuCzIDeAUMssFgFzIg4C2ARtKTXHRNQM5hSgDmLAA68kAfTYYc4arUbMyw4GIQ4oUCCAQBPLj37EAvsWIIMIbsjpb02PAQC8RFhWoAGADQsQbDsgBEALJaaJi4+H6eCiIQ4nSS0sgAjK4eQtGiKmoa2tR+gDUEEYYsxDBS+MBmyAAWcCBYADYQAPIMAFYQ+ABiwBD1WACqglhwkAAUMD191ADWEFoYMCG2+O7IAG5w9Ti+3LwgfACUTmRWNmFgANoTvVgAusiOG1sQhkA)

Link to not compiling [Typescript 4.3 Example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.3.2#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgApQPYBMCuCzIDeAUMssFgFzIg4C2ARtKTXHRNQM5hSgDmLAA68kAfTYYc4arUbMyw4GIQ4oUCCAQBPLj37EAvsWIIMIbsjpb02PAQC8RFhWoAGADQsQbDsgBEALJaaJi4+H6eCiIQ4nSS0sgAjK4eQtGiKmoa2tR+gDUEEYYsxDBS+MBmyAAWcCBYADYQAPIMAFYQ+ABiwBD1WACqglhwkAAUMD191ADWEFoYMCG2+O7IAG5w9Ti+3LwgfACUTmRWNmFgANoTvVgAusiOG1sQhkA)

What would an updated implementation for the handleObjectFieldUpdate function look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure to assign the right type of the `value` to the corresponding field, and it'll compile:

```
function handleObjectFieldUpdate(field: keyof Product, value: string) {
  if (field === 'id' || field === 'price_amount') {
    myProduct[field] = Number(value);
  } else {
    myProduct[field] = value;
  }
}
```

Comment: I See. I think the error message coming from typescript should be more expressive about this behavior as it's a welcome addition to the type safety. Thanks for clarifying.